# Unreplied message - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `messages` that stores users message, and the table structure looks like this:

Messages:

```
id   from_id    to_id  content        read_at
1    1          2       ABC           2014-02-28 16:36:39
2    2          1       BCC           2014-02-29 16:36:39
3    1          2       EFG           2014-02-29 18:50:39
4    4          2       GHJ           2014-02-29 16:36:39
5    2          4       MNX           
6    15         10      LKH           2014-02-30 16:36:39
7    20         6       LKH           
8    21         11      LKH           2014-03-03 17:46:40
```

How can i get unreplied messages from above table?

Expected Output:

```
   id      from_id  to_id  read_at
   6       15       10     2014-02-30 16:36:39
   8       21       11     2014-03-03 17:46:40
```

**New messages:**

An user received a message but haven't read it yet.

example:

```
 id   from_id    to_id  content        read_at
  5    2        4       MNX           
  7    20       6       LKH
```

**Unreplied messages:**

An user received a message and read it but haven't replied yet. However, only for the first message of the conversation will be considered as unreplied message.

Example:

```
id   from_id    to_id  content        read_at
8    21         11      LKH           2014-03-03 17:46:40
```

**Edit:**
The query i have tried:

```
SELECT from_id, to_id, count(id) as count
  FROM messages
  where read_at is not null
 GROUP BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), 
          GREATEST(from_id, to_id)
 having count < 2;
```

Comment: Do you have a query, where you try do do that?

Comment: @Michal, I have added my query

Comment: why would we assume those two were unreplied to? just because they occurred before unread messages?

Comment: The unreplied messages would essentially be the newest message sent by a user. so basically, find the newest for each user, see if there is a newer one where that user is the to_user, and if not, it's unreplied

Comment: @Anthony, Actually I need to find out only the first message which is not replied by the receiver. I am not sure i should call it unreplied or something else. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I see. a user could send multiple messages in a row that go unreplied to, right? I was thinking that if a message was not replied to, it must be the last one in the conversation. Which does raise the question of how you define a message as "replied"? If I send a user 5 messages in a row, and that user finally sends one, are all 5 replied to, or just the last one, leaving the other 4 without reply?

Comment: Hang on, looking at your example table again, I see that the messages between "1" and "2" are not in your expected output section. So "not replied" means "never replied" as in the conversation was started by user 21, but user 11 did not send a response after reading. This is tricky, though, because this means that if user 11 responds to any message from user 21, no future messages will be considered "not replied", correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it. That's exactly i want to implement. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns the expected results. I also tested with multiple un-replied messages to the same user and from different users to the same user, etc, to confirm that the `GROUP BY` and the `MIN(date_read)` were returning just the earliest row of an un-replied message, but still showing each to/from user combination.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8a80/1

```
SELECT outgoing.*, MIN(outgoing.date_read) 
FROM   messages AS outgoing 
       LEFT JOIN messages AS incoming 
              ON outgoing.from_id = incoming.to_id 
                 AND outgoing.to_id = incoming.from_id 
WHERE  incoming.id IS NULL 
       AND outgoing.date_read IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY to_id, from_id;
```

Notice, by left joining the table to itself where the `to_id` is the `from_id` and vice-versa, we know that only joined rows where the joined table returns `NULL` are either unread or not replied.

Then, by using the aggregate `MIN(outgoing.date_read)` column along with the `GROUP BY` on the `to_id` first and then the `from_id`, we know we'll only get the earliest date for each grouping and that it will show all `from_id`s for each `to_id` without repeats.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from messages m1 
left outer join messages m2 on
CONCAT(m1.from_id, '-',m1.to_id)  = concat(m2.to_id,'-', m2.from_id) 
where concat(m2.to_id,'-', m2.from_id) is null 
and m1.read_at is not null
```